# Recover mysql database from AMPSS installation on mac

Tags: mysql, database, macos, ampps

I develop websites locally using AMPPS on Mac.
After upgrading mac OSX AMPPS is not working anymore and it doesn't look like this is going to be fixed.
How can I recover all my databases from my AMPPS installation so that I can upload them on another working software to continue developing my websites and restore my local websites portfolio?

Thank you very much!
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mySQL databases are intact on the Mac and you have the password, you could use the `mysqldump` tool or similar to back them up and then move the backup file wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply Tim, I tried to run mysqldump but the software is probably 32 bit and I cannot run it anymore on Mac Terminal. I did another installation of AMPPS after the first one stopped working, now I have two installation of AMPPS on my computer, one working and one not. I can do a mysqldump on the working and active installation of AMPPS but not on the previous one. Is there any way to extract the databases from the older not working installation? Can I open some files and extract the database from it?

Comment: My knowledge of MySQL is on Linux so YMMV. But MySQL stores its files in a standard location. By default on Linux this is `/var/lib/mysql`. On the Mac I *believe* that it's /var/mysql. You could try extracting that, however, you might be better using some other backup software. Percona used to do an excellent backup product called xtrabackup which I believe supports MacOS